# Boost Python enum_ max value issues

Tags: python, boost, enums, crash, max

```
enum MyEnum
{
    SOME_NAME = 2147483648;
};

...

enum_<MyEnum>("MyEnum")
    .value("SOME_NAME", SOME_NAME)
;
```

While this compile fine, it crashes on initialization cause enum_ is casting values as "long" which is limited to `2147483647`. I'd need them to be unsigned long. Is there any way to do that without having to create an entire enum wrapper?

Thanks!

Comment: I have seen explanations of this issue on SO before. Did you search?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31618198/85371

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34332372/boostpythonenum-large-uint32-crash

Comment: C++ allows you to implicitly cast an enum to an int, not an unsigned int.  You're capped to INT_MAX as the maximum value.

Comment: @ScottM: I can't award a bounty to a comment.

Comment: Ok. Added as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

C++ allows you to implicitly cast an `enum` to an `int`, not an `unsigned int`. You're capped to `INT_MAX` as the maximum value. Furthermore, you have to cast an `int` (or an `unsigned int` that becomes sign-converted) to convert it back to an `enum`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you typecast `long long` instead of `long`, or `unsigned long`
Also maybe `unsigned long long`

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx