# boost::python::enum large uint32 crash

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I am trying to wrap a c++ enum using boost::python (boost 1.58). An enum is of type uint32_t and all values are wrapped without problem except large numbers, starting at 0x4000 0000.

An attempt to wrap enum value (uint32) of 0x4000 0000 lead to crash at enum.hpp, line 95 (boost 1.58). i observe this behaviour with VS2012 (win7).

Any ideas?

example:

```
enum EnumName: uint32_t
{
   valueOK = 0x20000000,
   valueCrash = 0x40000000
};

boost::python::enum_<EnumName>("EnumName")
        .value("valueOK", valueOK)
        .value("valueCrash", valueCrash)
        ;
```

Comment: Do you have a minimal example handy?

Comment: That's the part that was pretty obvious. See sscce.org and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Perhaps you should tell use what "crash" means and how you know it's in that line. I'm thinking you may be misrepresenting the problem here.

Comment: i think this is related to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31616231/boost-python-1-48-fails-when-exporting-32-bit-enum

Comment: Certainly related, although the analysis there doesn't inspire much confidence. Even if right, use 64 bits and report as a bug to Boost Python devs!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue. Using

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/35110d3b3bf99340)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

enum EnumName: uint32_t
{
   valueOK = 0x20000000,
   valueCrash = 0x40000000
};


EnumName identity_(EnumName x) { return x; }

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    boost::python::enum_<EnumName>("EnumName")
        .value("valueOK", valueOK)
        .value("valueCrash", valueCrash)
        ;

    //boost::python::def("identity", identity_);
}
```

Building:

```
g++-5 -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -fPIC -fsanitize=undefined -g -O0 -isystem /home/sehe/custom/nonius/include -isystem /usr/include/python2.7 -pthread test.cpp -c -o test.o
g++-5 -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic -fPIC -fsanitize=undefined -g -O0 -isystem /home/sehe/custom/nonius/include -isystem /usr/include/python2.7 -pthread test.o -shared -o test.so -lpython2.7 -lboost_python
```

Using

```
$ python2.7 <<< 'from test import *; print (EnumName.valueCrash+0);'
1073741824
```

Comment: i am struggling with this under win7 and vs2012. it is still strange, because at the place, where it crashes, enum.hpp, line 95, it tries to cast the value to long (signed long). how come you do not observe this under unix..

Comment: See my comment at the question. Is what you lazily call "crash" a compiler error?

Comment: sorry, yes, it is indeed not a "true" crash.. i am just wondering how to "cast" python enum to larger base..

Comment: Why don't you... start with showing the exact compiler message. Keep in mind that integral types are not the same on all compilers and warning levels could cause errors on implicit conversions

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x114A30E3 (name.pyd) in python.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000001.

Comment: Cool. That is just an access violation - a true crash. I'd have to defer to someone with windows, or find time later. Could you add the missing info to the question for now? (While you're at it, you can take my SSCCE and update your question with it too, provided it reproduces the problem for you!)